# Determine whether the following expression is positive

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions

I am faced with a problem where I need to show that an expected expression is positive. But I fail to give a strict proof.

$$A=E_v \frac{v_2^2-v_3^2}{1+K+\lambda_1(v_1+m)^2+\lambda_2v_2^2+\lambda_3v_3^2}-E_v \frac{v_2^2-v_3^2}{\alpha+K+\lambda_1v_1^2+\lambda_2v_2^2+\lambda_3v_3^2}$$

Where $K,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,m$ are positive real numbers and $\lambda_2>\lambda_3$; $0<\alpha<1$. $v$ is random variable vector whose elements are independent and subject to Guassian distribution with zero mean and variance $\alpha$. That is $v \sim N(0,\alpha I).$

I have evaluated $A$ through simulation with different $K,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,m$, the result shows $A$ is always positive. I wonder anyone can give an analytical result to prove or disprove this problem.

Thank you :)

Comment: Is $\nu_2 > \nu_3$? How about the signs of $E_\nu$?

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't have any any priori conditions on $m$ and ${\rm sgn}\, E_\nu (\nu_2^2-\nu_3^2)$ there are three possibilities.

First we observe that if $m \geq 0$ then the denominator of the second expression is positive and the denominator of the first expression exceeds the latter. It follows that
$$\frac{1}{1+K+\lambda_1\,(\nu_1 + m)^2 +\lambda_2\nu_2^2+\lambda_3\nu_3^2} < \frac{1}{\alpha+K+\lambda_1\,\nu_1^2 +\lambda_2\nu_2^2+\lambda_3\nu_3^2}.$$

Case 1: $E_\nu (\nu_2^2-\nu_3^2)=0$ This provides a negative result as then $A=0$.

Case 2: ${\rm sgn}\, E_\nu (\nu_2^2-\nu_3^2) = +1$. This also gives a negative result since then $A <0$.

Case 3: ${\rm sgn}\, E_\nu (\nu_2^2-\nu_3^2) = -1$. This gives a positive result since now $A > 0$.

So it all depends on the signs of $m$, and ${\rm sgn}\, E_\nu (\nu_2^2-\nu_3^2)$. The interesting case is where $m < 0$. So which is it?